# Remote access to postgresql on yocto

Tags: postgresql, yocto

Since I am using yocto everything is a bit different. Using common linux systems (such as ubuntu) postgresql is running out of the box and I know how to access it via editing pg_hba.conf.

On yocto everything seems to be a bit different. Here is what I tried:

- After starting yocto postgres is not running. I checked that with **netstat -tulpn**
- Therefore I switched to user "postgresql" (has been created by me) and started postgres: **pg_ctl start -D /my/path/to/dbFolder**. Log says:

> database system is ready to accept connections

netstat shows me now that a local port has been opened:

> tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      266/postgres

However, my pg_hba.conf includes the following line:

> host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust

But pgAdmin III on my remote system reports

> could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit postgresql.conf,

```
listen_adresses = '*'
port = 5432
```

pg_ctl restart